# how pass function between sibilngs components in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

so i have 2 component are sibiling one call  and 
and i went to pass a function from NavBar component to Login component
i try to do that becouse i went when the user login i can call to function from the NavBar to update the state in the Navbar component

i add here the code of 2 components

this the NavBar component and i went to pass the userLog function from her

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import Login from "../auth/login/Login";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import './navBar.css'

function NavBar() {

    const [cookie, setCookie] = useState(null)

    const userLog = () => {
        if (localStorage.getItem("login")) {
            setCookie(true)
        }
    }



    const logout = async () => {
        console.log("logout")
        const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/logout', { withCredentials: true })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data.status == "success") {
                    console.log('sss')
                    setCookie(false)
                    localStorage.setItem('login', 'false')
                }
            })
    }


    return (
        <div className="nav-bar-container">
            <img className="imgLogo" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAABLFBMVEX////CwsLoigZvb2/gZALnewD8//+/v7/8/PzDw8NtbW35//9nZ2f+/v9qamplZWXNzc329vbs7Oze3t7W1tb7//zgWwDm5ubhYgDmgwDg4OCsrKyTk5P//frurljohgDpgQDzxaqIiIj//PTw///fXADndQDliwj89e3lWADcZAn87eTmokPnYADhjAmcnJx+fn7vwIf45tD48tjz06zms4zdhEf95dDt0bv75cj73sTuwYzfjlvkrV3obxr2fQDkmybwv5XsqX/2zJ3lnG/tyKrkfzrx0aT49ePgdSzuoFHttoTszLvskm/kkFHXahHsrGrplCzrn2jquHbonD/nkD7xvZ/agjzxq2zkpT3z4bnloDbhlWHqgELonVHno3ThkwDvvW/kSgDksFaVYcPzAAAOQElEQVR4nO2bC1vayBrHI5fJwBASkHARYrLGSICKSvGGtduqKLZn11pt92y7e7q75/t/h/POJIFwsZXAY/uc5/35tFXASf7z3gcqSQiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAjy/4yhKGxJSzHJIGRJay0RRbeV5axk2BIzlrPUUnneZfZyVmLM3rd/QBt2tu4MSV9475lEjNZB2daXcU/L5dCynrUWd1Qw3lG5mPgRFR7HYlb9eOFlGNlvNMs/pMKeFWub5omkKzTy3RFDsl+AwHLZ+BEVVuommPHUJcSIGo325uFLp5lIJIo/rsL6z68GJHIwsr5T5gK/s0JDgaowLaJrcYWxunl7qCsKnd+MBpFeO+CgwobulEKiU/ZEJYQ+txmZ3mJfIThqrLdpR/BTJp052wmPaYWEMNJyo93xvCin7ZPn0w3aUGHdrJxLEcqGfdEoJ5oPKtQPvzQ/RrzlOSHrlllfPyaSYYR1DhUClfN5sw2x9ReNxJBxhTpcq39ZdIo/LUXAt1kHJab16spl4dvoWrER1h6z5+rhdOOgmJitENzT3U80nGbzCRXWY2bdtNon4ZTTTYYVxvagMM6xpnEZFlhuhBTqnQun0Wwmyk+pUIRbzKzU9wY6Mah41N2Lha1Y2SMGoWMiFIkM+v2jAS/sY1BmHxShkfHlJRrXr70G19AZ6CsW+YNPr5BjWrET15909E33pB7SaJ2wcSsS9vzNVnJrK/l2MJH1iX3gBOZztp2X/7I3hQkZI51fnG0/+3wXhfU6t6MXcJTqxN6LjbJN7GRinDquJJNbSfjz62B8Qf2XYnMYgTc/EZvZouITsF+5GRj3CRWemrEwZvtKJzq4FbdYa90caewyZdSbELvC5XG23myOeldqM9AhvDCR2E58sXmCpgwc1D0rOp7bfmeF4Kv3x5J/x0S5agca29YxCYXc20AgSDwcObDB9huiDIKxGpeHTOcurNtM/5hoDGPzOyvkOeedH1uGQQanFV95PdYZ9ahGZcsaSnwTaor6kCiFDcvNfQOKjHiG9H5rjBz0iRWSd1ZsCnBVgxlUJE9yHmQc8zZIKgbpjUwI0WgEj7MjYalmouncHPqPgYN+ccLiPJ7OhjMUghnNZy2IRoUfSZHOK/8l9Td+28PI65DC5FbLU0iMQaJ8Uxa3fxB0ekw6upkh8OkUkr/NKYUgsWLFzkWl0yGpuuuep5qVO++X9DGFW1sdT7mxeV1u8hTTbOyzIPvYf/AM+j0V3lm8p6lPy7TuB56n6oq9V/E0Wt4RnM3GbdgRKxmb74siwspOnz+gQBgzMOC0Oi6wXDx6IoXd9TpPoNOWrFv1ri3MqCjsPEipLW4aXQrHYTI5gAeZTWDi5UFYvumJI2CDEH2/4Y2I45Qdx7n+tfM0CilT7E4X6p45pbEes+7ESacO42rXN+wznn6YMdhKDjVufeBNO9FbCdGwlK87myJJGWxwAJm1OR6EZZD38n2/o8+YSqOzuprP0a+9gNjHr28rltWux8wxM94/Dw6sj0W6Ma09yEDw47tAYGVrqy/CkFwKAyZedhhci+oG6zUnPBTqSNE5+DjDeLAlVPwN5Na0ampOhWuyLK9o2sM6KQFf7Jw/s0wzHJEwc9Q/+acNxJPYtjpCc2sUhR9shT/y0REKX+ZEX6ArZL84kULLTvHFxwF5+PgiV9KqtXgmk1XX5lSYW0mtrKyATDmlFUozZBJKKeQF2rmLjUUknx3P/U1gPfgRJN8Lz2X9QKDVYgo80ipzH3WuW4ZOYMMUG9LOaMAAIPQ+DiD30JnjdG5V3tmNq5lsOg5fG9JXXW4GhZUhQiZY07/vyVfa3WeVsEgzVrkjflfWNXlGhZFf4gWjW+GzxdaHjsgq+oHXyIifmEHc30YjIk82RefX3uRhCfWvn9eqG2khzicjz6kP1pBTKyGRKS4TjDn1OkXXdXJ4V6+ENNatdb9nIWLyN+steCGFMbD/7/dvuzqPOoO9dkQWPdzkm2GzznXIRWFGbO7DBDLhnVwdXZNrWVXNxsdQKZ3XhlJYoHDZFDcmuOzkSlDEdDLYa480mjHrd1fy7HbOjWiuw+ABs7KuM0KYLpzObYp5ogc+CM026934c2CZl8fi9U82z5yT3pmXa/EsqEuP64tnd2Y417dYlVdmwRPQai7Y0JFMabBXj43Sqnnrek2Y6A9ilU9js6ICle/MKTcbXqEHLb2m76Ll5k25cdMff3fNS5ur1V1wzPgs1NV55QG52Qo9W6YKeTquUYFa9rZuhSX60wZv4MwP+tiGUOY2mk7T+Sj6PEM6aiSGVb6RAH2TBx05bSetZidNF5DejSCQDnNNalKhl2U9kYE+BSQqrPVO5FLR0ZntFhF9uH0L9cS6Gl/duHDKN40LosDOSOzIEfOTyJ/NfRjwxw8jc1ot84DxIucZzniumeWvqcJ45oEScHxvtdtegTRfiX6Nsk4bquTtmFFoB9KMcynKoE56jj9KNLeLf3RC/smzBy3U0tmvyeM2zEdSCLkGJD7kq55GWVsLeZ9i68w++TnwVOsV3wDoVK4qsXayG/JqYl9A6Wt2NrmLsk4xceMphACE58L3UKrGH7ZeNp1RedLheSYSq1xFoVTQeKkIPDZkV+6u8ERhtIGKQgkZ/D58B+OzTRQK7csedD63oa0gnSKMEz1iQ7PDDsuJbV4Bwahn0LcbIxtSbeOB2EuDNjWzW6tqG16emTuRCkSuKYhL5UqrXCe36LTrypqoIMFFdOWK9+DCUdfFuZJuPzNjZjfoV+EfmACLZ1wqWFDYrwzT33VvdG1YLA/mmyEPXDYjtJVEBdyFh6LkGQ+NG2qYM2ku78mc4a6p1VFEUlty7/0Z33on2hflOX/XzT8gBit1wIJ/Ei6euJdeHSwXL9xwB1PayWZmpBQ1E6/Jfo7jf+XVyHmGkwc1cn48zUOrO3LawF25cYcaoYPW9T1LmLFt7Yl6QPj7Nsf+Sgw67GaiBY0adKMvilAnyuXtRF/SR8PRWm0q+rhf7la1UE7hNpRhGzLTndZjoTzQpmsppRCbQmRYqCyDRl8DZcaxd8Zv8kNT/tCdaZ76BXLTbiYakFL4QH/Gs+h20znoBPMD5frUia4lq2Y2qoUZSmrp6HmGX4v3NdrMZ3xbTqTWVV+hQYky+A9PNzBbHXLT2MatafpH3azfcP4gYEAbvuNTRLPxxR6V+PxOZlLe7o6WG146fBs52IlMIbJCL9ekHvQBml9NyV6GHcZjyVNoUEWx31ltPvXfu3ArBjmumDBiKDy7vHCuXcg3dJOnVPhq9OEJ/w2eXFX4Z3rom5nd6toDmZJKa2o8uzt/zx1Cgxj7ajXNrWpeih1qHL2cXCX5QYf5DiY8aHrukve6wj02X2yIdpTp196p/SHjFlT4jabiQX7hGjOZja9fXs7Gs9WIpcIDcs2MQJwQWUiNxWNhWDakT23o4kzrimdRkru1jsVJy/4/F97QIA7anJeu/1FEKpU21JBzBvIeFEAlqIZqfhGFlOeaWYE4Qb7gV0quNXBVnhs7f1l84ODtm6L3Knug0GDXCZcY8NXn7ws6B/AD82bb6qi8pzPxammk5AFy6XS6Fl2egOeax2wRLWncWb1WVtaGRbT1ymrXK+K4TdFPYww66pbwUcIGUOqhLOpU8V5d2h0WwIxaKzzmqgU1ri6SZzg5+RuBGHrp0Fshyfq/YzD31rJiUBXFeGV2mMH2L/lRokIOoFcrXsD3XvmuqiHzTQ+gM6lCUooobIT27UAcQnluTXFXTcne1hrQtHzmH5YaKKCEnL8GQb91oHnlPrp90ziDEOQjvpTbyAyjT3t0XO3yPLMokGseEYgBtBTYUdaC+u9+TsbMe/G5DftUsd0vOoNa6N5wgUGfVohn/dK3MYfX5TLxTMS5KXzPqZT82D0Vhw15TQRjKqgbhp57ZcIELE7Ujm39aMAUyC3vG1Dng3MYWU17+mqrwSHvYyhksovmGbGMPNGafpO8aOlSK7J3SKvo7mezXXfhG4PZzDvc6DkwKxE+KcG27IgQTKu10lfXnaKazWgLFUMP6GvmPeaheeGrqSCC7da9Zf4d/oANu3SKF4ao/0EIZjbmvAxUw3R8cX2AJs8RiFJwqJnivupXf8paf5lQ7ocKyWvHOWDEGwN3eQhm4trc54G5tLp4nuGU5EdVxDDieEUOKiOfpzpm7NSfgME37YTzp22IMpjnOSabjTLiFVR18TzDyT26Io4D4QiO6qd+8smqHPqZ0yD70HqLXlQqcYHqTqTOq6ouI89wCo+viCP4Ha/JgRWh9F8l1/2niAvzr/efYrjAdFwLfmE+NtT5wudhcnMGYgCMb7yV03j6h87sJNmRqMIn4P1/Dvk8qAgXzexEzBYwGy40N4XR5g7EIWvQ9fn7o5/eE3G27zb6THw0NReHVjtyX1lQF5ubwpSiBaLwPDCj38FR+/aTeHP77AvxpqXddKaWi+KfgqpaWpZCSqF2R14Lkqoo/YpBWv8FN9Xdg01JHIrWMmr0UzIIw40FfnmSwkIhXeKjhtih445NlK4rDlHBBvFVr9GLBF1anuHkHt2aziS/IotxSKfPc0R3jU2+mqbuLlTN1rLLCkIO1aIfSXJyWsq7HfEBBZ0313m1ttgdysvpZwLW5uyJxwFX1MZTJqXx6Kec3pLztunfWnDRswKqjd/QzmKZHpxg/g9ffJ0o7yKPM3ZirS3sYnl5yQrziwUiJ/QWWG7R26PSrCP+hVakS1hwtER+jkH+ARao0AiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIAiCIIvzP0XRbJlXXZz3AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" />
            <ul className="main-nav">
                <li><NavLink className="navLink" to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink className="navLink" to="/">Contact</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink className="navLink" to="/login">Login</NavLink></li>

                {/* {cookie === true ? <li><NavLink className="navLink" to="/">username</NavLink></li> : <li><NavLink className="navLink" to="/login">Login</NavLink></li>} */}
                <li><NavLink onClick={logout} className="navLink" to='/' >Logout</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink className="navLink" to="/sign-in">Signin</NavLink></li>
                {/* <button onClick={() => user()}>user</button> */}
                {/* <button onClick={() => log()}>dddd</button> */}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );

}
export default NavBar;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

this the Login component and i went to get the userLog function and call it in the login function that i call by onClick

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Login.css'



function Login(props) {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
    const [password, setPass] = useState("")
    const [cookie, setCookie] = useState(Boolean)


    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation()

    const login = async (props) => {
        console.log(email, password);
        try {
            const res = await axios.create({ withCredentials: true }).post(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/login`, {
                email: email,
                password: password

            });
            if (!res) {
                return "not work"
            }
            console.log(res.data.data.user)
            localStorage.setItem('login', 'true')
            navigate("/", { replace: true });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };




    return (
        <div className="pop-container">
            <div className="popup">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1>Sign in</h1>
                    <div className="input-field"><input placeholder="Email" className="validate" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} /></div>
                    <div className="input-field"><input placeholder="Password" className="validate" onChange={(e) => setPass(e.target.value)} /></div>
                    <button onClick={(e) => login(e)} className="second-button">Sign in</button>
                    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="/signup.html">Sign Up</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I try to use useLocation and also pass state in NavLink in the NavLink component
but thay cant get a function
to pass some date like string i success its not a problem but function I not success

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct way to pass between sibling components. One option is to pass from sibling 1 -> parent component -> sibling 2. So with your "NavBar" and "Login" components you can lift state up from Navbar to the App (parent) component and then down to the Login component.

Option 2 would be setting up something like a [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) hook. Context is for setting global state variables to avoid unnecessary prop drilling.

Comment: Thanks it worked
But there is one problem because it is a state as soon as I refreshed the page the information was lost
And the result of the condition of the state if it is true or false is canceled